# Application migration from IIS 8.5 (Win Server 2012 R2) to IIS 10 (Win Server 2016) problem with ASP.NET page and VB.NET code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, migration, iis-8.5, iis-10

I looked for an advice everywhere but I did not find anything :( my problem resides in a page of an ASP.NET application created with **VB.NET** code, after the migration from **Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5** to **Windows Server 2016 with IIS10** only this page gives me error when browsing on the network.

When I run the test by doing "*Browse*" from IIS no problem.I have come to the conclusion that in the code of the page (which I report below) there is some line that is no longer recognized by **IIS10** for security reasons.

Can you tell me if you notice something strange? I report below the details of the error reported by EVENT VIEWER; it seems that the error it's in the row 28

***EVENT VIEWER ERROR:***

> Exception information:  Exception type: IOException  Exception
>   message: The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator 1.CommonInit() at
>   System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator 1..ctor(String path, String
>   originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption,
>   SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) at
>   System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern,
>   SearchOption searchOption) at
>   it_prod_ship_xmlparser_it.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\drivetools\it\prod\ship\xmlparser_it.aspx.vb:line
>   28 at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Drawing

Partial Class it_prod_ship_xmlparser_it
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Session("utente") = UCase(funzioni.usr)
        If Session("utente") = "ITXXXXXX" Or Session("utente") = "ITXXXXXX" Then
            btnXML.Enabled = False : btnBart.Enabled = False : btnTrackC.Enabled = False
            btnLbl.Enabled = False : btnTel.Enabled = False : btnTrack.Enabled = False
            AsyncFileUpload1.Enabled = False : gvXML.Enabled = False
        End If
        Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo("\\servercompany.it.company\drivefiles\xmlfiles")
        Dim listfile As FileInfo() = folder.GetFiles("*.xml")
        If listfile.Length = 0 Then
            btnXML.Enabled = False
        Else
            Dim fsize As Double = 0
            For Each f As FileInfo In listfile
                fsize += f.Length
            Next
            btnXML.Text = "Importa (" & listfile.Length & " - " & Math.Round(fsize / 1024 / 1000, 1) & " Mb)"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for all the information you can give me

Comment: Make sure the application pool identity has the permissions to access that UNC path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm sure that the identity pool is able to write and read inside the shared folder ... Some of you are aware of new security checks performed by "Windows Server 2016" and "IIS 10 " that did not appear in previous versions (" Windows Server 2012 "and" IIS 8.5 ")?

Comment: Use tools like Process Monitor to analyze please.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank everyone who responded and gave me important information to analyze the problem.
After months of attempts that drove me crazy, I found out that my issue was caused by the new security settings: when switching from a "Windows Server 2012 R2" to a "Windows Server 2016" the security features "DEVICE GUARD" and "CREDENTIAL GUARD" were called into action on all clients that required access to web pages that in turn required DELEGATION rights (for example when it was necessary to browse network folders in the name of the user who had opened the web application).
I solved it by setting the correct SPNs on the servers involved in authenticating the application.
Thanks again to all